# Running erlang shell command, via console, in an already-running shell

Tags: linux, shell, erlang

Good morning !

I'm trying to set up a communication between an erlang shell and an external function (zenity) that communicates only via scripts.(It can only run command lines)

In my program, the erlang shell is already running and spawned nodes that I need. (So opening an other shell to run the functions doesn't work, and `escript` opens a new shell. I need to run the functions from my main shell)

This is what I manualy do, and would like to script it.

```
$ erl -name two@127.0.0.1 
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
(two@127.0.0.1)1> c(client). 
{ok,client}
(two@127.0.0.1)2> client:init(). 
true
(two@127.0.0.1)3>
```

The `client:init()` spawns threads. And I communicate with them via some functions.

From here I run my different functions with

```
client:<function>(<Args>).
```

But a script whith

```
erl -name two@127.0.0.1
c(client).
client:init()
client:<function>(<Args>).
```

Obviously, it does not work.

I can shorten this a bit with

```
$ erl -name two@127.0.0.1 -s client init
```

But I still can't run functions on the shell that was created, because the function to call depends on the outputs of Zenity that only communicates via shell command lines

Are there solutions to run erlang command via a script ?

Comment: You're looking for [escript](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html).

Comment: When you say "depends on the outputs of Zenity", do you mean that Zenity prints messages to standard output that you want to act on, or does it actually return useful values that you can use?

Comment: If I understand well, Zenity pops graphic windows, displaying infos, or asking for an entry. And allows to read that entry and run a shell command.
For example, opens a box, ask the age, the user fills it, if age > 18, Zenity runs `$ <command line 1>` and else, run `$ <command line 2>`
And I want this command line to run a function on an existing erlang shell

Comment: If you generate a node/release with rebar (rebar generate-node node-id=foobar), it will create a load of stuff for you, including a shell script for starting and stopping your node, communicating with it, and other stuff. It communicates with it by way of 'nodetool', an escript it generates for you, which makes RPC calls. You can then add commands to these scripts to achieve whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have you to run a command from `zenity` but not just grab result? (Or you can run `echo`.)

```
1> Port = open_port({spawn_executable, os:find_executable("zenity")}, [in, {line, 65536}, eof, {args, ["--calendar", "--title=Holiday Planner"]}]).
#Port<0.490> 
2> flush().
Shell got {#Port<0.490>,{data,{eol,"10/20/2016"}}}
Shell got {#Port<0.490>,eof}
ok
```